# Why is Array .filter method returning an empty array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

The below is really confusing me, I am trying to filter the musicData array to only have contents where the artist + name length are less than 25.  I have logged out through the iterations etc. and everything looks good, so i'm completely stumped why it returns an empty array.

Any help would be much appreciated.

```
const musicData = [
    { artist: 'Adele', name: '25', sales: 1731000 },
    { artist: 'Drake', name: 'Views', sales: 1608000 },
    { artist: 'Beyonce', name: 'Lemonade', sales: 1554000 },
    { artist: 'Chris Stapleton', name: 'Traveller', sales: 1085000 },
    { artist: 'Pentatonix', name: 'A Pentatonix Christmas', sales: 904000 },
    { artist: 'Original Broadway Cast Recording', name: 'Hamilton: An American Musical', sales: 820000 },
    { artist: 'Twenty One Pilots', name: 'Blurryface', sales: 738000 },
    { artist: 'Prince', name: 'The Very Best of Prince', sales: 668000 },
    { artist: 'Rihanna', name: 'Anti', sales: 603000 },
    { artist: 'Justin Bieber', name: 'Purpose', sales: 554000 }
];

var totalAlbumSales=musicData.filter((curr) => {
    curr.artist.length+curr.name.length <25
})
```

Answer (score 4):

You forgot the `return` keyword to indicate what should be returned to the new array. Without that, you are just executing a statement.

Since your logic to determine what should be in the filtered array could easily be comprised of many statements, the `return` keyword is needed to explicitly indicate what goes in the result.

See documentation on **[Array.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)**

```js
const musicData = [
    { artist: 'Adele', name: '25', sales: 1731000 },
    { artist: 'Drake', name: 'Views', sales: 1608000 },
    { artist: 'Beyonce', name: 'Lemonade', sales: 1554000 },
    { artist: 'Chris Stapleton', name: 'Traveller', sales: 1085000 },
    { artist: 'Pentatonix', name: 'A Pentatonix Christmas', sales: 904000 },
    { artist: 'Original Broadway Cast Recording', name: 'Hamilton: An American Musical', sales: 820000 },
    { artist: 'Twenty One Pilots', name: 'Blurryface', sales: 738000 },
    { artist: 'Prince', name: 'The Very Best of Prince', sales: 668000 },
    { artist: 'Rihanna', name: 'Anti', sales: 603000 },
    { artist: 'Justin Bieber', name: 'Purpose', sales: 554000 }
];

var totalAlbumSales=musicData.filter((curr) => {
    return curr.artist.length + curr.name.length < 25
})

console.log(totalAlbumSales);
```

Comment: thanks for your response, how do I know when I need to use the return.
e.g. [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)
In first example return isn't used

Comment: `return` is used within functions to literally return control to the caller of the function (thereby exiting the function), but it can also be accompanied by a value to be returned to the caller as well. `.filter()` is designed to return an array, but your custom callback must decide what to return into that array. See this for more on **[`return`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return)**

Answer (score 3):

You are missing the `return` keyword to make it a statement.

If you want to write that callback without a `return` then simply remove your brackets.

From [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions):

> (param1, param2, …, paramN) => { statements }
>
> (param1, param2, …, paramN) => expression
>
> // equivalent to: => { return expression; }

**Demo**

```js
const musicData = [
    { artist: 'Adele', name: '25', sales: 1731000 },
    { artist: 'Drake', name: 'Views', sales: 1608000 },
    { artist: 'Beyonce', name: 'Lemonade', sales: 1554000 },
    { artist: 'Chris Stapleton', name: 'Traveller', sales: 1085000 },
    { artist: 'Pentatonix', name: 'A Pentatonix Christmas', sales: 904000 },
    { artist: 'Original Broadway Cast Recording', name: 'Hamilton: An American Musical', sales: 820000 },
    { artist: 'Twenty One Pilots', name: 'Blurryface', sales: 738000 },
    { artist: 'Prince', name: 'The Very Best of Prince', sales: 668000 },
    { artist: 'Rihanna', name: 'Anti', sales: 603000 },
    { artist: 'Justin Bieber', name: 'Purpose', sales: 554000 }
];

var totalAlbumSales=musicData.filter((curr) => curr.artist.length + curr.name.length < 25);

console.log(totalAlbumSales);
```

Comment: *If you want to write that callback without a return then simply remove your brackets.* That only works when there is a single statement in the callback body though.

Comment: yes but whats wrong with my sentence? I'm talking about *that* and not *a* callback

Answer (score 0):

You weren't returning from the filtering function. Here you go.

```js
const musicData = [
    { artist: 'Adele', name: '25', sales: 1731000 },
    { artist: 'Drake', name: 'Views', sales: 1608000 },
    { artist: 'Beyonce', name: 'Lemonade', sales: 1554000 },
    { artist: 'Chris Stapleton', name: 'Traveller', sales: 1085000 },
    { artist: 'Pentatonix', name: 'A Pentatonix Christmas', sales: 904000 },
    { artist: 'Original Broadway Cast Recording', name: 'Hamilton: An American Musical', sales: 820000 },
    { artist: 'Twenty One Pilots', name: 'Blurryface', sales: 738000 },
    { artist: 'Prince', name: 'The Very Best of Prince', sales: 668000 },
    { artist: 'Rihanna', name: 'Anti', sales: 603000 },
    { artist: 'Justin Bieber', name: 'Purpose', sales: 554000 }
];

var totalAlbumSales=musicData.filter((curr) => {
    return curr.artist.length+curr.name.length <25
})

console.log(totalAlbumSales)
```